# how can i make all if statements in a loop ? in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, button

i've already tried a for loop but I'm new to javascript so it's all still hard for me. I am grateful for any help.
It should increase values.
here´s my code:

```
prestige_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
if(prestige_plus == 2){
  taxi_pro_sec *= 3;
  gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *=  3; 
  zeitungAustragen *= 3;   
  mehrLimoStände += 3;
}
if(prestige_plus == 3){
  taxi_pro_sec *= 4;
  gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *= 4; 
  zeitungAustragen *= 4;   
  mehrLimoStände += 4;
}
if(prestige_plus == 4){
  taxi_pro_sec *= 5;
  gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *= 5; 
  zeitungAustragen *= 5;   
  mehrLimoStände += 5;
}
if(prestige_plus == 5){
  taxi_pro_sec *= 6;
  gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *= 6; 
  zeitungAustragen *= 6;   
  mehrLimoStände += 6;
}
if(prestige_plus == 6){
  taxi_pro_sec *= 7;
  gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *= 7; 
  zeitungAustragen *= 7;   
  mehrLimoStände += 7;
}
if(prestige_plus == 7){
  taxi_pro_sec *= 8;
  gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *= 8; 
  zeitungAustragen *= 8;   
  mehrLimoStände += 8;
}
}});
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(const num of [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]){
    if(prestige_plus===num){
      taxi_pro_sec *= num;
      gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *= num; 
      zeitungAustragen *= num;   
      mehrLimoStände += num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop like this:

```
for(const num of [2,3,4,6,7,8,9]){
    if(prestige_plus === num ) {
        taxi_pro_sec *= num + 1;
        gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *= num + 1;
        zeitungAustragen *= num + 1;
        mehrLimoStände += num + 1;
     }
}
```

Answers could be better if you would describe your scenario some more.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use :

 prestige_btn.addEventListener('click', function(myNumber){
    if(prestige_plus == myNumber){
      taxi_pro_sec *= myNumber + 1;
      gartenArbeit_all_five_sec *=  myNumber + 1; 
      zeitungAustragen *= myNumber + 1;   
      mehrLimoStände += myNumber + 1;
    } 
 });
```